# Input and output format with PHP and SQLSRV

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I have a fairly specific scenario that I'm struggling with.  The frustration is that it shouldn't even be complicated!

I have a SQL database and I'm connecting to it using PHP + SQLSRV.  The database structure is quite straight forward and currently has 2 varchar columns (ColumnA and ColumnB for this example).

My task is to read the data from this table, allow the values to be edited in a form and write back to the database.  **This part is easy enough and is all working.**

The challenge now is that the database values need to be written to my (currently empty) values.php file in the following format.

```
<?php
    $output = array (
        "Val1" => 'aaa',
        "Val2" => 'bbb',
        "Val3" => 'ccc',
    );
?>
```

Ideally, I'd like this to be done at the time of the save to database command which I can do as part of an AJAX success process so that part shouldn't be an issue

I started working on the following process;

```
<?php     
$sql = "SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB FROM Table";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn2, $sql );

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
$test[]= array($row['ColumnA'] ." => '". $row['ColumnB']."',");
$values =  implode(PHP_EOL,$test);

}

$content = '<?php
$output = array ("'.$values.'");
?>';

file_put_contents("c:/jjj/values.php", $content);

?>
```

This gives me a lot of "Array to string conversion" errors and the file gets populated with;

```
<?php
$output = array ("
Array
Array
);
?>
```

Where am I going wrong here?

**EDIT**

After the various comments below, the current code reads as;

```
<?php     
$sql = "SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB FROM Table";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn2, $sql );
$test = [];
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $test[] = [$row['ColumnA'] => $row['ColumnB']];
}

$content = "<?php" . PHP_EOL;
$content .= "\t" . '$output = [' . PHP_EOL;
foreach($test as $key => $value) {
    $content .= "\t\t\"{$key}\" => \"{$value}\"," . PHP_EOL;
}
$content .= "\t];" . PHP_EOL;
$content .= "?>";

file_put_contents("c:/jjj/values.php", $content);
?>
```

This results in 3 Array to string conversion errors (One for each row) and an output file that looks like this:

```
<?php
    $output = [
        "0" => "Array",
        "1" => "Array",
        "2" => "Array",
    ];
?>
```

I still can't find a way to export my DB table to a file in the correct format using PHP.

Comment: why are you imploding with a newline?

Comment: To try and get the output format to match the expectation?  If I output $test instead of $values, I get the correct values in the wrong format!

Comment: Don’t create “code” for this manually - use `var_export` instead!

Comment: var_export won't allow me to output the file in the correct format.  It's all about the file format at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will come closer to what you want:
To echo tabs as well you could use \t within the double quotes

```
$content = "<?php" . PHP_EOL;
$content .= "\t" . '$output = [' . PHP_EOL;
foreach($test as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
        $content .= "\t\t\"{$subkey}\" => \"{$subvalue}\"," . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
$content .= "\t];" . PHP_EOL;
$content .= "?>";
```

Comment: The output with this option comes out very similar to my original output except the array name is missing in the file that's written.  I also still get a number of Array to string conversion errors displayed on the page where I'm running this.

Comment: Still not working @sietse85.  Undefined variable output (Because of the double quotes) - Changed to   $content .= '$output = [' . PHP_EOL;
Also get a number of undefined index values because of the "{$line['ColumnA']}\" and "{$line['ColumnB']}\" values

Comment: nested foreach was the correct answer.   Thank you so much!